# Java reflection - get generic method from non-generic class

Tags: java, generics, reflection

is it possible to get a generic (parametrized) method from a non-generic class through reflection?
Here's a sample of what i want to do:

```
public interface GenericInterface<T> {
    public T publicMethod(T arg);
}

public class NonGenericClassWithGenericMethods {
    private <T> void privateMethod(GenericInterface<T> arg) {

    }
}

public class Generics {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            NonGenericClassWithGenericMethods.class.getMethod("privateMethod", GenericInterface.class).setAccessible(true);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If i run Generics, i get:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   NonGenericClassWithGenericMethods.privateMethod(GenericInterface)

Thanks everybody

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.getDeclaredMethod()` should be used instead of `.getMethod()`, which returns only public ones.

Comment: Thanks that's it! I was too concentrated on type erasure for noticing that it just was a matter of visibility :)